# (dart:mirrors) - isAbstract for ClassMirror?

Tags: dart

Is it possible to figure out if a class is abstract from a ClassMirror?  I see this is possible with methods via MethodMirror, but I don't see any way to determine whether or not a class is abstract or not.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Dart team added isAbstract to ClassMirror, so I'm all set!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this isn't possible. Perhaps you can file a request for this feature at https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/list.